# Making CSS changes (index)

Tags: css, wordpress

Using a child theme on my wordpress to update css.

Using the parameter:

```
.homepage .title {
         color: ffffff;
}
```

There is an index css that [seems to be interfering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/senkz.jpg) (index:58)? I can't seem to locate that line in any of my theme parent files. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I think you should make it more clear about what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inline the css in the head of HTML. If you click on the (index:58) in developer tools it will show you the code that's applying the style.

Simply remove the `.homepage .title { color: #000000}` from the head of the html

[Inlined CSS rule in the head of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT4bI.png)